# orgmode - latex new line in tikz node not work

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, preview-latex

Below code works fine if copy the tikzpicture to tex file. but in orgmode, looks like the new line not take effect!

```
#+header: :imagemagick yes :iminoptions -density 300 -opaque white -flatten -geometry 800 :fit yes :noweb yes :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}") :border 0 :results raw
#+begin_src latex :eval yes :file debug.png
;; https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/android-zygote-boot-process/
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
  \def\desc{
Description1:\\
- line one\\
- line two\\
- line three
,
Description2:\\
- line one\\
- line two\\
- line three
    }
  \foreach \d[count=\i] in \desc {
      \node[on chain] (P\i) {\d};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src
```

I try to use \\ also but not work either!

[image]

Comment: Could you try to encapsulate the text of each node in a \parbox. For instance :

\parbox{1.1cm}{
Description1:\\
- line one\\
- line two\\
- line three}
If this gives the right result I will write is as a solution.

Comment: exactly, add parbox works fine, Is it possible to make parbox auto fix text width? if use a fixed size, text maybe longer than it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two ways to obtain the expected result:

1. Fixed width: use a \parbox to enclose the paragraphs:

`\parbox{2cm}{ Description1:\\ - line one\\ - line two\\ - line three}`

2. Variable width: use a \tabular to structure the paragraphs:

`\begin{tabular}{l} Description1:\\ - line one\\ - line two\\ - line three \end{tabular}`